# I stripped the thermocouple adapter on the gas valve on my hot water heater so I cannot connect the thermocouple.

Tags: water-heater

I can tell the connection piece has threads, is there a way to unscrew that piece and replace with a new one?  The nut sheared off. Is there a way to alternately connect the end of the thermocouple to the gas control valve?[image: This is the nut that is sheered off from the gas control valve]

Comment: "Stripped" normally means that you've partially damaged the threads of a fitting.  Here it looks like you totally broke off the piece of the valve that the thermocouple screws into right?  I don't see a fix other than buying a new valve.

Comment: Man, I did the same thing. Gonna try drill and tap to get broken piece off the threads as the valve is not removable. Don't try and open the valve either it has springs and gaskets that a tricky to reassemble, nor can you get to the broken area anyway by going through the valve's case.

Comment: By the way the reason it happened is I (wrongly) unscrewed the valve's adaptor where the thermocouple enters the valve instead of the thermocouplers brass fitting that goes into the adaptor..you have to be careful !! Going by touch and being out in the rain did me in, plus my vision is so bad in my old age...

Answer (score 3):

Safest and easiest repair is to purchase a replacement at the hardware store. It isn't worth trying to repair a part that primarily functions as a safety device.

You may need to replace the valve if your existing thermocouple isn't removable or if the warranty is expired, bite the bullet and replace with a new unit.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that simple.  The silver bit on the thermocouple, that's supposed to be attached to the heater (I think).

Comment: The silver end goes to the valve (I believe), but I've seen both types (replaceable and not).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the silver part, is part of the valve.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the piece that I needed to have was not fixable and could only replace with a new gas valve.  Thank you very much for all of your help.